# How to supply ios device token to AWS Pinpoint

Tags: ios, token, aws-pinpoint

I'm unable to perform Direct Messaging using the AWS Pinpoint console. Each attempt results in  a "Failed to submit push notification to..." error whether I provide an EndpointID or a DeviceToken. I'm guessing that I am not providing a valid device token.

On iOS, the deviceToken is delivered as an NSData object. I can print it's value to the console as string by using [deviceToken description]. This is the string I pasted into the Direct Message console (after trimming angle brackets and internal space chars). Is this the expected way to generate a string from the native deviceToken for AWS messaging? My other guess, [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would do this:

```
deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
```

But after checking AWS documentation website basically they are saying to print the device token and remove the spaces.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken 
{
    NSLog(@"deviceToken: %@", deviceToken); 
}
```

Please check this website:
[Getting Started with Apple Push Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `Data` object already contains a method to do this easily

> deviceToken.toHexString()